How can I export schema data from oracle apex cloud free account?
How can I export data from tables in oracle apex cloud free account ?
I need to generate insert statements and insert the data to MAXAPEX paid account
I searched for that but I cannot find the way , also I don't know how to export the schema tables and data using
EXPDP utility 

from oracle apex free account
So I generated DDL script from SQL WORKSHOP for tables but I need the data also
How can I generate insert statements script ?

You can do to with an ORACLE "OCI Free account" because you will have the wallet to access the database, you have to install instant client + the exdp/impdb tools on your computer or on your free compute instance, create the cloud object storage storage, the needed data bucket, a "datadump" credential... lot of steps but it works.

You could also use the "data packager" feature that was introduced in apex 21.2. here is a demo video.

thank you its working and data imported but should arrange the script first put the tables with primary key data then FK tables data

Agreed, but that is not always possible because of circular references. It is probably easier for you to remove the fk constraints before packaging the data and then adding them again after import.

I don't think you can. expdp is an operating system command prompt utility, and you don't have that.
One option (though, works for a single table at a time) is to use Data Workshop's Data unload. Here's a walkthrough (follow the wizard between steps 3 and 4):

You'd then import (load) such a comma-separated file into the target table (database).

but this will not generate complete insert statement it will generate the data only so i need to insert the data again or make the insert statements one by one ?

Nobody said it'll create INSERT INTO statements. As you can see for (3), you can unload data as a CSV file (my example) or XML format. On the left hand side is the Load data button; behind it is a wizard which leads you through the loading process (again, table-by-table).

can I login using toad or SQL developer to oracle cloud database and how can I get the host , port and service name ?

You can't, as far as I can tell. Why? Because you don't know info you already mentioned.
